# Confused about classification of simple lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the classification of simple lie algebra, I learnt that $\mathfrak{sl}(n + 1)$ has a root system $A_n$. For example http://stacky.net/files/written/LieGroups/LieGroups.pdf, page 82. But I found elsewhere that the simple lie groups corresponding to $A_n$ is $SU(n + 1)$. For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group.

Could somebody explain to me why this is not $SL(n + 1)$ as I would naively expected? Isn't the corresponding simple lie groups are just lie groups generated by the simple lie algebras we just classified?

Comment: the classification is for the base field $\mathbb C$. When you complexify $su$ or real $sl$, you get complex $sl$. There is always one real compact form ($su$ in your case), but also several non-compact forms (eg. $sl$, but also $su(k,l)$ in your case).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, different Lie groups may have the same Lie algebra. For example, the Lie algebras of $PSL(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ are both isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Secondly, different real simple Lie algebras may become isomorphic over the complex numbers, e.g., $\mathfrak{so}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}})$. The complexification is in both cases isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{\mathbb{C}})$.

Comment: Hi Dietrich Burde, thank you for your answer. So the point is that $\mathfrak{su}$ and complex $\mathfrak{sl}$ are the same once I complexify the former? Or do you mean the lie algebra of $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is the same as $SU(n)$? (Because I didn't know they were). So is there anything wrong if I say $A_n$ corresponding to $SL(n+1)$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $\frak{sl}(n)$ have isomorphic complexification. And $A_n$ need not correspond to $SL(n+1)$, not even over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So that means the lie algebra of $SU(n)$ is not $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ because I have to complexify it first? Meaning my understanding that finding the corresponding simple lie group means finding lie group with given simple lie algebra is wrong?

Comment: The Lie algebra of $SU(n)$ is $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, which is not isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$. And to a Lie algebra, there may exists different Lie groups having this Lie algebra.